# Getting the sencha touch 2 operation object within PullToRefresh plugin

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need to set the start param (operation.setStart(1)) when refreshing my list using the PullToRefresh sencha touch 2 plugin.

I can do this just fine within the onJsonpstoreBeforeLoad function, because this function parses the `operation` parameter object

```
onJsonpstoreBeforeLoad: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
    /* some before load operations */
    var startIndex = operation.getStart();

    /* increase the value of the start-index by one */
    operation.setStart(startIndex+1);
}
```

But within the PullToRefresh plugin's "on refresh" function, it only parses the `plugin` parameter, but I need to get the `operation` in order to use setStart()

```
....
refreshFn: function(plugin) {
    console.log(Ext.data.Operation);
}, ....
```

Does anyone know how to get the current operation? I can get the store/proxy using `plugin.getParent()` but this does not help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call

```
plugin.up();
```

Hope this help!!

Comment: Thanks, this does allow me to get the list (which is the parent of the plugin) however I still cant get the operation? The only class which has this method is the request `Ext.Request.getOperation()`.. how do I get the operation in order to set `setStart()`